# Pandas: Get all columns that have constant value

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get the names of the columns which have same values across all rows for each column.

My data:

```
   A   B  C  D
0  1  hi  2  a
1  3  hi  2  b
2  4  hi  2  c
```

Desired output:

```
['B', 'C']
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'A': [1,3,4], 'B': ['hi','hi','hi'], 'C': [2,2,2], 'D': ['a','b','c']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I've been playing around with `df.columns` and `.any()`, but can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: *" Get all columns that have constant value" / "only have a single value"*

Comment: Is performance important? Then check timings in my answer.

Comment: In fact there was an existing duplicate [Select pandas dataframe columns which have only one unique value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49099163/select-pandas-dataframe-columns-which-have-only-one-unique-value). Should we close that into this? (because this has more answers) @jezrael you answered both!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use the pandas not-so-well-known builtin [***`nunique()`***](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html):

```
df.columns[df.nunique() <= 1]
Index(['B', 'C'], dtype='object')
```

Notes:

- Use `nunique(dropna=False)` option if you want na's counted as a separate value
- It's the cleanest code, but not the fastest. (But in general code should prioritize clarity and readability).

Comment: @Mohamed Thasin ah solution is the fastest for my dataset (30.000 rows 195 columns), however since I value readability over speed on this one, I go for your `nunique()` solution - thx!

Comment: This answer works only on the provided sample data but does not answer the question. If one of the columns has two rows with the same value it will reported with this answer and the question is about columns with constant values. `pd.Series(data=[1, 2, 2, 3]).is_unique` => `False` and this is of course the expected behaviour of such method

Comment: @Mousa: The second solution I showed, using `df.nunique()==1` does work. Updated this. Thanks for the comment

Comment: `nunique` with `dropna=True` (the default) reports cols with only `NaN`s as zero, thus `df.nunique()<=1` seems to be the more general solution.

Comment: @NichtJens: excellent, thanks for the refinement! `nunique()` is totally underdocumented and so are recipes involving it... must file some docbugs/enhances on pandas docs.

Comment: Only example that can shows columns with missing values too.

Comment: @vasili111: create your own example for that, it's trivial. I showed the working code for it.

Comment: I already created it. I made that comment for other readers that your example is only one in this thread that can properly solve problem with column filled with missing values. I do not asking any additional code.

Answer (score 8):

Solution 1:

```
c = [c for c in df.columns if len(set(df[c])) == 1]
print (c)

['B', 'C']
```

Solution 2:

```
c = df.columns[df.eq(df.iloc[0]).all()].tolist()
print (c)
['B', 'C']
```

**Explanation for Solution 2**:

First compare all rows to the first row with [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html)...

```
print (df.eq(df.iloc[0]))
       A     B     C      D
0   True  True  True   True
1  False  True  True  False
2  False  True  True  False
```

... then check each column is all `True`s with [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html)...

```
print (df.eq(df.iloc[0]).all())
A    False
B     True
C     True
D    False
dtype: bool
```

... finally filter columns' names for which result is True:

```
print (df.columns[df.eq(df.iloc[0]).all()])
Index(['B', 'C'], dtype='object')
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(1000,100)))

df[np.random.randint(100, size=20)] = 100
print (df)

# Solution 1 (second-fastest):
In [243]: %timeit ([c for c in df.columns if len(set(df[c])) == 1])
3.59 ms ± 43.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# Solution 2 (fastest):
In [244]: %timeit df.columns[df.eq(df.iloc[0]).all()].tolist()
1.62 ms ± 13.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

#Mohamed Thasin ah solution
In [245]: %timeit ([col for col in df.columns if len(df[col].unique())==1])
6.8 ms ± 352 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

#jpp solution
In [246]: %%timeit
     ...: vals = df.apply(set, axis=0)
     ...: res = vals[vals.map(len) == 1].index
     ...: 
5.59 ms ± 64.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

#smci solution 1
In [275]: %timeit df.columns[ df.nunique()==1 ]
11 ms ± 105 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

#smci solution 2
In [276]: %timeit [col for col in df.columns if not df[col].is_unique]
9.25 ms ± 80 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

#smci solution 3
In [277]: %timeit df.columns[ df.apply(lambda col: not col.is_unique) ]
11.1 ms ± 511 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: @smci - Thank you.

Comment: I'd beware of claiming `len(set(df[c]))` is in general faster than the native pandas `len(df[col].unique())`, this toy example only has 3 values. Try it on a bigger df. `set(df[c])` could blow out memory if used on a large string or categorical column.

Comment: @smci - tested in bigger DataFrame, `pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(1000,100)))`

Comment: and len(set(...)) is still faster? can you post the timings?

Comment: @smci - my timings are with larger dataframe only, not with sample OP data.

Comment: See my answer `df.columns[ df.nunique()==1 ]`. Care to time it?

Comment: There's also a builtin [Series.is_unique](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.is_unique.html)

Comment: `df.columns[ df.apply(attrgetter('is_unique')) == False ]`

Comment: Since the index information isn't really needed, it'd probably be faster to do `df.columns[(df.values == df.values[0, :]).all(0)]`.

Comment: I think this answer should be the accepted one. Please check this comment on the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50582168/pandas-get-all-columns-that-have-constant-value#comment102170681_50582784

Comment: How to show also columns that have only missing values?

Comment: @vasili111 - Do you think `df.loc[:, df.isna().all()]` ?

Comment: That leaves only columns with missing values. I collected some examples that work fine with different data in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61199019/1601703

Answer (score 3):

try this,

```
print [col for col in df.columns if len(df[col].unique())==1]
```

Output:

```
['B', 'C']
```

Comment: pandas now has a builtin [`df.nunique()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set` and apply a filter on a series:

```
vals = df.apply(set, axis=0)
res = vals[vals.map(len) == 1].index

print(res)

Index(['B', 'C'], dtype='object')
```

Use `res.tolist()` if having a list output is important.